# 2x2x2 repeated measures anova: do I correct for type I error?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have a 2x2x2 repeated measures design and am trying to decompose a 3-way interaction. 
As all my factors have 2 levels, I always reach the point that I am doing pairwise comparisons for the simple effects. I have not managed to find a clear answer as to whether I should correct my p.values acquired from these dependent t.tests.

From what I am seeing happening in 2-way designs, it implies to me that I should not correct. For example, if in a 2x3 anova the interaction is broken down with 2 one-way anovas comparing the 3 levels of IV2, and the only correction is for the comparison between these 3 groups only and not for the levels above that (just like if simply a one-way anova with 3 levels was being carried out in the first place), then does this mean that if the same interaction was broken down with 3 t.tests there would be no type-I correction?

If this inference is correct, I suppose that even in my 2x2x2 design, there should be no correction.. (?)
 If I am wrong and I need to adjust p, how can I compute how many comparisons emerge from a 2x2x2 anova so that I can correct accordingly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably haven't found a clear answer as to what you *should* do because there isn't one that doesn't depend on what you *want* to do. If you want to control the chance of one or more Type I errors over all tests, then correct for multiple comparisons; if not, don't.